# Difficulty with my lexical analyzer

Tags: c, regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to program a lexical analyzer to a standard C translation unit, so I've divided the possible tokens into 6 groups; for each group there's a regular expression, which will be converted to a DFA:

1. Keyword - (will have a symbol table containing "goto", "int"....)
2. Identifers - [a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
3. Numeric Constants - [0-9]+/.?[0-9]*
4. String Constants - ""[EVERY_ASCII_CHARACTER]*""
5. Special Symbols - (will have a symbol table containing ";", "(", "{"....)
6. Operators - (will have a symbol table containing "+", "-"....)

My Analyzer's input is a stream of bytes/ASCII characters. My algorithm is the following:

```
assuming there's a stream of characters, x1...xN
 foreach i=1, i<=n, i++
    if x1...xI accepts one or more of the 6 group's DFA
    {
       take the longest-token
       add x1...xI to token-linked-list
       delete x1...xI from input
    }
```

However, this algorithm will assume that every byte it is given, which is a letter, is an identifier, since after an input of 1 character, it accepts the DFA of the identifiers tokens ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*).

Another possible problem is for the input "intx;", my algorithm will tokenize this stream into "int", "x", ";" which of course is an error.

I'm trying to think about a new algorithm, but I keep failing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why? `gnu-flex` already exists.

Comment: I'm programming a compiler.

Comment: "I'm programming a compiler." -- Uh, so? That's not inconsistent with using flex. But if you must roll your own ... a lot has been written about how to write lexers, and I suggest you read some of it, because your approach sucks, is horridly slow, and yields the wrong results.

Comment: @RonPinkas Gee, Ron, I would certainly want to know that my approach sucks, and I can't comprehend not understanding why.

Comment: @RonPinkas Perhaps you didn't read my comment, which served a lot more purpose that these comments of yours do.

Answer (score 2):

Code your scanner so that it treats identifiers and keywords the same until the reading is finished.

When you have the complete token, look it up in the keyword table, and designate it a keyword if you find it and as an identifier if you don't find it.  This deals with the `intx` problem immediately; the scanner reads `intx` and that's not a keyword so it must be be an identifier.

I note that your identifiers don't allow underscores.  That's not necessarily a problem, but many languages do allow underscores in identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Tokenizers generally FIRST split the input stream into tokens, based on rules which dictate what constitute an END of token, and only later decide what kind of token it is (or an error otherwise). Typical end of token are things like white space (when not part of literal string), operators, special delimiters, etc.

Comment: FWIW I did develop a generic lexer engine, which might be of some help in understanding many common issues. It should be fairly readable, plain C code. http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplex/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It also is not generally correct, as what constitutes the end of a token can be context-dependent. Not taking that into account can lead to some unfortunate results; e.g., in C, `0xe + 1` is legal but `0xe+1` is not, because of the definition of "preprocessor token". The C standards committee tried to patch up the rules to fix this but ran out of time and voted to leave this wart in the language.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the `greediness` aspect of competing DFAs. `greedy` matching is usually the most useful (left-most longest match) because it solves the problem of how to choose between competing DFAs. Once you've matched `int` you have another node in the IDENTIFIER DFA that advances to `intx`. Your finate automata doesn't exit until it reaches something it can't consume, and if it isn't in a valid accept state at the end of input, or at the point where another DFA is accepting, it is pruned and the other DFA is matched.

Flex, for example, defaults to greedy matching.

In other words, your proposed problem of `intx` isn't a problem...

If you have 2 rules that compete for `int`

1. rule 1 is the token "int"
2. rule 2 is IDENTIFIER

When we reach

`i` `n` `t`

we don't immediately ACCEPT `int` because we see another rule (rule 2) where further input `x` progresses the automata to a NEXT state:

`i` `n` `t` `x`

If rule 2 is in an ACCEPT state at that point, then rule 1 is discarded by definition. But if rule 2 is still not in ACCEPT state, we must keep rule 1 around while we examine more input to see if we could eventually reach an ACCEPT state in rule 2 that is longer than rule 1. If we receive some other character that matches neither rule, we check if rule 2 automata is in an ACCEPT state for `intx`, if so, it is the match. If not, it is discarded, and the longest previous match (rule 1) is accepted, however in this case, rule 2 is in ACCEPT state and matches `intx`

In the case that 2 rules reach an ACCEPT or EXIT state simultaneously, then precedence is used (order of the rule in the grammar). Generally you put your keywords first so IDENTIFIER doesn't match first.